# Thymeleaf and inline scripts SAXParseException

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, cdata

I got a page which uses thymeleaf template, and I'm getting the following error on page load when using inline scripts:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 270; columnNumber: 85; The
>   content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or
>   markup.

Code at line 270

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
```

I have tried replacing "<", ">" symbols from document.write with `&lt;` `&gt;`, the exception doesn't occur anymore but the script is not loaded anymore

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add CDATA tags for the script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
     window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    //]]>
</script>
```

The tags are telling thymeleaf's xml parser that the code between should not be interpreted as XML markup.

**This is no longer necessary since Thymeleaf 3.0**

Comment: For more information , [Thymeleaf templating engine parsing tweaks] (https://anwaarlabs.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/thymeleaf-whitelabel-error-page-convert-html-to-thymeleaf-template) can helpful.

Comment: It works. Took a lot of time to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this worked for 1.5.2! This issue has been resolved in 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Hopefully they release 2.0 soon.

Comment: Just as an update, Thymeleaf 3.x uses the AttoParser and CDATA isn't needed anymore, as long as you do not want to validate your markup against xml.